# it is possible to use quantum algorithm search (Grover's algorithm) for new searching strategies for differential and linear attacks

Tags: block-cipher, post-quantum-cryptography, linear-cryptanalysis, differential-analysis, quantum-cryptanalysis

I am trying to use Grover's algorithm to find  Differential characteristic of Feistel and SPN structures block ciphers. basically, which is Finding a good differential characteristic with high probability in the (related-key) differential attack

For example, using  Matsui’s Algorithm to Search for related-key differential
characteristics in DES-like ciphers by Alex Biryukov, Ivica Nikolic.:  FSE 2011

also using Integer programming-based method ( Differential and linear cryptanalysis using mixed-integer linear Programming ) by Nicky Mouha, Qingju Wang, Dawu Gu, Bart Preneel Inscrypt 2011.

my question

can construct Grover's algorithm to find  Differential characteristic of Feistel and SPN structures block ciphers?

Comment: I recommend to read Marc Kaplan, Gaëtan Leurent, Anthony Leverrier, María Naya-Plasencia "Quantum Differential and Linear Cryptanalysis"  
https://doi.org/10.13154/tosc.v2016.i1.71-94

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Grover's algorithm is a probabilistic quantum algorithm that finds (with high probability) the unique input to a black box function that produces a particular output value, using
$$
O({\sqrt  {N}})
$$ evaluations of the function, where the fuction has domain of size $N$.
is the size of the function's domain.

Keeping in mind the fact that the spedup is only quadratic, unlike Shor's algorithm which provides exponential speedups on a different problem,  it can be applied to any search problem over a finite domain.

The normally suggested countermeasure to this algorithm in the symmetric crypto setting is quite mild: symmetric key lengths can be doubled to compensate for the risk.

**Edit:** For multiobject search for $\ell$ objects, Boyer et. al. in [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9805082) proved the following theorem, which as pointed out by @poncho in the comments, is a bit counterintuitive.

**Theorem:** (paraphrased) *Assume that $\ell/N$ is small. Then
any search algorithm for $\ell$ objects, in the form of [grover search]
takes on average $O(\sqrt{N/\ell})$ iterations in order to be successful with positive probability $>1/2$
independent of $N$ and $\ell.$*

1. M. Boyer, G. Brassard, P. Høyer and A. Tapp, Tight bounds on quantum searching, Fortsch. Phys. 46 (1998), 493–506. See related paper on arXiv [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9805082)

Comment: Actually, Grover's algorithm can handle the case where there are multiple 'winning' entries; however counterintuitively enough, you *must* decrease the number of iterations.   Not "you can reduce the number of iterations, you have to; too many actually reduces the probability of the algorithm finding the solution.

Comment: thank you for the clarification and this suggested research article